# Dynamic Data Iterator Value Change During Training in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

My Data Loader :

```
LoadData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, ..., ...., ...):
        self.ns = (640, 640)
        .....
        .....

   def __getitem__(index):
       img = resize(img[index], self.ns)
       .....
       .....
       return img

   def set_size(self, ns):
       self.ns = ns
```

And the training loop

```
for img in dataiterator:
    forward(img)
    backward()
    datatiterator.dataset.set_size(new_ns)
```

I would like to resize images dynamically after each iteration. When I do it as above, it does not work. Is there any simple trick to do that? Please help.

Best,

Comment: Do you want in each iteration to change the size of an image? Or do you want it as part of augmentation? Do you have a set of sizes to choose from?

Comment: I want to change the size of an image-batch at each iteration, yes.